# Error creating django url (matching query does not exist)

Tags: python, django

I just start to develop with django and I am stuck...

I have my models.py:

```
 from django.db import models
class Meeting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    latCoord = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
    longCoord = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    participants = models.IntegerField()
    latCoord = models.FloatField()
    longCoord = models.FloatField()
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^(?P<meeting_id>\d+)/$', 'meeting.views.meeting'),
                       url(r'^add_location/(?P<meeting_id>\d+)/$', 'meeting.views.add_location'),
                       url(r'^create/$', 'meeting.views.create'),
                       )
```

and my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from meeting.models import Meeting, Location
from forms import MeetingForm, LocationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core import serializers
import math
import encodeUrl
def meeting(request, meeting_id = 1):
    l = Location.objects.filter(meeting_id = meeting_id)
    ...
    ...

    return render_to_response('meeting.html', 
                              {'meeting': Meeting.objects.get(id = meeting_id), 'data':data})

def create(request):
    print "test"
    if request.POST:
        form = MeetingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/meetings/%s' % len(Meeting.objects.all()))
    else:
        form = MeetingForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('create_meeting.html', args)
```

so far everything works fine. The url for every new meeting is the meeting/meeting_id.
Now I want the url to be a string instead of a number. So I changed the code:

urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^(?P<meeting_id_str>\w+)/$', 'meeting.views.meeting'),
                           url(r'^add_location/(?P<meeting_id_str>\w+)/$', 'meeting.views.add_location'),
                           url(r'^create/$', 'meeting.views.create'),
                           )
```

and the views.py

```
    def meeting(request, meeting_id_str = 'b'):
    #encode the string to an integer
    meeting_id = encodeUrl.alphaID(meeting_id_str, True)
    l = Location.objects.filter(meeting_id = meeting_id)
    ...
    ...
    ...    
    return render_to_response('meeting.html', 
                              {'meeting': Meeting.objects.get(id = meeting_id), 'data':data})

def create(request):
    print "test"
    if request.POST:
        form = MeetingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            meeting_id_str = encodeUrl.alphaID(len(Meeting.objects.all()), False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/meetings/%s' % meeting_id_str)
    else:
        form = MeetingForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('create_meeting.html', args)
```

the encoding works and if i call a url eg meeting/b  it is changed to meeting/1 but when I want to create a new meeting I get the "query does not exist" exeption

```
 Request Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/meetings/create/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Meeting matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'id': 3945298144L}

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 389
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

every hint is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never going to enter `create`, because the first pattern - `r'^(?P<meeting_id_str>\w+)/$'` -  also matches "create/". You should move the create pattern so it's first in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in these lines of your create view.

```
...
meeting_id_str = encodeUrl.alphaID(len(Meeting.objects.all()), False)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/meetings/%s' % meeting_id_str)
```

I think you are expecting that `id` of last object created is equal to number of objects in DB, but that may not be true.

Try updating the create view code as

```
....
if request.POST:
    form = MeetingForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mobj = form.save()  #get object created using form
        meeting_id_str = encodeUrl.alphaID(mobj.id, False) #use its id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/meetings/%s' % meeting_id_str)
else:
....
```

Comment: thanks for the usefull answer but that does not solve the error. Even if I redirect to eg /home the exeption ist thrown, the function create is not entered ?!